# Objects From Group, list order issues - Animation Nodes

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes, groups

I run Animation Nodes to drive shapes on a rig with bones - such a better solution to Drivers.

But currently the shape Group list I use to select that particular object (needed for updating the rig and keeping the group relatively dynamic)gets the object list order mixed up sometimes.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to sort the group object list order with Animation nodes?

Comment: How do you want to order them? based on what I mean?

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a fixed indice. For example Object A is Indice 1, Object B is Indice 2, and so forth. Currently getting the AN group list the Object A and Object B order changes randomly before I can get the correct indice.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of object `[Object B, Object A, Object E, Object C, Object D]` and you wish to order them as `[Object A, Object B, Object C, Object D, Object E]`, simply construct a list such that its elements are that of the list at the indices `[1, 0, 3, 4, 2]`.

[image: Node Tree]